# How do I get nan_values in pandas' read.csv to say "Set as NaN if it contains the character 'C' in any cell"

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to set my nan_values through pd.read_csv to be any string that contains the character 'C'. In other words, if there is a 'C' in any cell, pandas should read it as 'NaN'.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

In [1]: df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',
        parse_dates={'timestamp': ['Date','Time']},
        index_col='timestamp',
        usecols=['Date', 'Time', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        na_values=['0', 'C'], #what should I change here?
        )

In [2]:df
Out[2]: timestamp        a  b   c   d   
2015-10-13 14:58:20 87  168 0.4 0000C000 #should be NaN
2015-10-13 14:58:22 87  168 0.3 0200C500 #should be NaN
2015-10-13 14:58:24 87  168 0.3 8000
2015-10-13 14:58:26 87  168 0.3 8000
2015-10-13 14:58:28 87  170 0.4 8000
2015-10-13 14:58:30 87  170 0.4 8000
```

The thing is, I know that I can set it to the Boolean false using str.contains(). But I don't know what the proper way to apply str.contains() to pd.read_csv's na_values.

```
In [3]: df['d'].str.contains('C')
Out[3]:timestamp
2015-10-13 14:58:20     True
2015-10-13 14:58:22     True
2015-10-13 14:58:24    False
2015-10-13 14:58:26    False
2015-10-13 14:58:28    False
2015-10-13 14:58:30    False
Name: d, dtype: bool
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you want to do this while reading from `CSV` , you can do this easily after getting your `df` from excel

Comment: what function would I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function that interprets your data as you want. In your case:

```
def readD(val):
    if 'C' in val:
        return numpy.nan
    return val
```

This functin can be arbitrarily complex. I use something like this when reading array-types from database-extracted data; so my cells hold python lists instead of strings like '{1;2;3;4}', for example.

Then pass a dictionary mapping 'd' to that function

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', (...), converters={'d': readD})
```